# What are the threading differences between pycharm in debug and run mode?

Tags: python, pycharm, python-multithreading, sentry

I've been writing some logging code for an existing script in python, and found this really odd situation.

Basically, sentry_sdk will log completely normally in debug mode, but in run mode the background logging thread will be killed before it's able to finish logging.

I've done some digging, and the biggest plausible reason I've discovered for this, is that the background logging thread is created as a daemon.

Does pycharm treat daemon threads different between run and debug mode?

Comment: sentry SDK hooks into atexit to block the main thread until the background thread has finished. Perhaps PyCharm ignores atexit in run mode.

Comment: you can try https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/python/configuration/draining/ to work around this issue if it is one for you

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I've actually had a colleague recommend that idea, but the sentry debug log both with/without using client.close() are identical, so I think it's still hooking into atexit correctly.

Comment: I'll make a small reproducible example, it'll just be a bit